# How can i be able to reorder this arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list defined as such

```
List<String[]> output = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

With values added to it as such :

```
String[] link = new String[3];
                    link[0] = page
                    link[1] = title
                    link[2] = pagerank
output.set(i, link);
```

- pagerank is double.

What is the easiest way to reorder "**link**" array to be sorted according to "**pagerank**" decending ?

Comment: I recommend you to create your own class and wrap `page`, `title` and `pagerank`.

Answer (score 6):

[Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) using a custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, there is also a nice API which does this for you: BeanComparator

so you could have link data as a class and use

```
Comparator<Link> beancomparator=new BeanComparator("pagerank");
Collections.sort(linklist,beancomparator);
```

refer: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html

Comment: Cool, didnt know this existed